# Access privilages to different level of users in windows application C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Am working on a college management software in which there are different level users such as Admins, Principals, Teachers. Each users have a different level of privileges. So that all the features are not available to all the users. Users will have their logins.

So my problem is how do i set this access to each features according to their level of privilege...???

Now i do this by checking privilege level at login time and set the feature menu item visible or invisible.

Is their any other best way to implement this....????

Advance Thank You.... :)

Comment: Post the code that is not working.  This is a simple authorization system shouldn't be hard.  You have usernames and passwords so give user a authorization level.

Answer (score 0):

You might delegate the show/hide items to a custom control which will encapsulate the logic to do that.

Comment: He should make a proper design for how to implement this instead of starting with a technical solution.

Comment: you are right. Mine is just a generic way to solve the problem